# Sync external planning with Google agenda private API

Tags: google-calendar-api

We're developing an agenda on our platform. We implemented a feature to sync with Google Agenda which works correctly except that it only works with public calendar and not when it's private.

We implement everything as Google provides and use AuthO2 protocol.

We are migrating to https and we hope that it will solve our issue.

Do you have any idea on the reason it's blocked when agenda is private?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement synchronization by sending HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

and adding path parameters and optional query parameters as shown in [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

In addition to that, referring to [Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync), you can keep data for all calendar collections in sync while saving bandwidth by using the "incremental synchronization".

As highlighted in the documentation:

> A sync token is a piece of data exchanged between the server and the client, and has a critical role in the synchronization process.

As you may have noticed, **sync token** takes a major part in both stages in incremental synchronization. Make sure to store this `syncToken` for the next sync request. As discussed:

> 1. Initial full sync is performed once at the very beginning in order to fully synchronize the client’s state with the server’s state. The client will obtain a sync token that it needs to persist.
> 2. Incremental sync is performed repeatedly and updates the client with all the changes that happened ever since the previous sync. Each time, the client provides the previous sync token it obtained from the server and stores the new sync token from the response.

More information and examples on how to synchronize efficiently can be found in the given documentations.